Kotlin compose multiplatform, cannot compile with pod SwiftGRPCClient
I'm trying to add the pod SwiftGRPCClient to my KMP project, but I keep hitting this error:

unsupported option '-G' for target 'arm64-apple-ios11.0' (in target
'BoringSSL-GRPC' from project 'Pods')

Most other pods work fine (not all, but the majority).
I'm currently using Xcode 16 beta on iOS 15.2 Beta.
Any ideas on how to resolve this? Thanks!
This is my gradle:
cocoapods {
        extraSpecAttributes["swift_version"] = "\"5.0\""

        summary = "This is sample Summary"
        homepage = "Home URL"
        ios.deploymentTarget = "15.0"

        version = "1.1"

        framework {
            baseName = "ComposeApp"
            isStatic = true
        }

        pod("SwiftGRPCClient") {
            extraOpts = listOf("-compiler-option", "-w")
        }
    }


It looks like that's a Swift-specific library. You can't use Swift code with cinterop unless it's Objective-C compatible.
You'll need to find an Objective-C gRPC client. That, or write some kind of wrapper.
